# Margin spacing of footer for landscape page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, landscape

I put a lot of time into figuring out how to have the page numbers on the long side of my landscape pages as per my school's formatting requirements (yes I'm sure) but now the numbers are apparently slightly too high. I need to make it 0.5 inch from the bottom of the page and centered in order to get my PhD. (I'm not bitter...)

Current code:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{floatpag}
....


\fancypagestyle{floatpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear page header/footer
  \fancyfoot{
    \makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Right
      \rlap{\hspace{\footskip}% Push out of margin by \footskip
        \smash{% Remove vertical height
          \raisebox{\dimexpr.7\baselineskip+\footskip+.5\textheight}{% Raise vertically
            \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}}% Rotate counter-clockwise
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
```

And then for the figure:

```
 \begin{landscape}
 \begin{figure}  
\centering\thisfloatpagestyle{floatpage}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{chapters/ProgrammedCellDeath/lyse_benefit.pdf}
        \caption{Science}\label{helping}
    \end{subfigure} %
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{chapters/ProgrammedCellDeath/explode_benefit.pdf}
        \caption{Science}\label{harming}

    \end{subfigure} 
\caption{Science is cool.}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact position is a little complicated to calculate.  Assuming we start at the right-hand side of the footer, then we want a vertical box centered at `.5\textheight + \footskip` above the baseline of the footer.  This needs to be pushed to the right by the width of the margin and then moved back on to the page by `.5in`.  The width of the margin is

```
\pagewidth-\textwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin
```

(have a look at the diagram in the `fancyhdr` documentation)
Putting this together we get:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\fancypagestyle{rotfloatpage}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\rfoot{\makebox[0pt]{\smash{\rotatebox{90}{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\textheight+2\footskip]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\textwidth+1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin-\paperwidth
  +.5in\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\thepage}}}}}}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\rotfloatpagestyle{rotfloatpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
    \caption{Science}\label{helping}
  \end{subfigure} %
  \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
    \caption{Science}\label{harming}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Science is cool.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Note I have used the `rotating` package rather than `pdflscape` as in combination with `floatpag` one set the corresponding page style for all such floats at once.

Answer (score 0):

This code did the trick:

```
  \fancypagestyle{floatpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear page header/footer
  \fancyfoot{
    \makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Right
      \rlap{\hspace{\footskip}% Push out of margin by \footskip
        \smash{% Remove vertical height
          \raisebox{\dimexpr6\baselineskip+\footskip+.5\textheight}{% Raise vertically
            \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}}% Rotate counter-clockwise
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
```

Just changed the dimrexp.7 to dimrexp6 though I still have no real clue as to why that worked and would love an explanation.

Comment: The `.7` or `6` is the multiplier for the `\baselineskip`, so you are adding a larger multiple of that number than before, and so moving the text.  However a correct computation should use more information.  See my answer instead.